# Delete entity of repeat in form and visualize result with update does not work

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have an List of Items, where I want to be able to add and remove items. For that, I add the whole List in a  and everytime add or remove an item, I call update from primefaces. The code looks like this:

```
<h:panelGroup id="group">
     <ui:repeat value="#{manager.values}" var="item">
      <p:inputText value="#{item.name}"/>
      <p:commandButton value="Remove" action="#{manager.remove(item)}" onsuccess="update_values();"/>
     </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>
<p:remoteCommand update="group" name="update_values"/>
<p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{manager.newValue()}" update="group"/>
```

Adding works fine, but everytime I call remove, the behaviour is strange. The item, which is the most right is deleted, and the name of the others remain unchanged, even if I remove the most left item.

After some debugging, I found out that this is because of the value="#{item.name}": The item is deleted correctly, but after the deletion, the value of the fields that exist are set for the values the fields had before. So all in all, the most right field does not exist anymore, because ui:repeat has one item less, but the others get the values they had before, so it is only possible to remove the most right field.

Has anybody an hint how to solve this? One solution maybe would be to clear every field with javascript, but I'd rather like the frameworks to solve the problem than to code something myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like so:

```
<p:commandButton value="Remove" action="#{manager.remove(item)}" update=":directPath:group" process="@this" />
```

maybe the fact that there is no hard update on the button itself might be the cause.

PS

Is there an `<h:form>` around your element?

Comment: Yes, there is an `h:form` around my element (so adding works fine), but the `commandButton` is inside the `h:group`, so if I say `update="group"`, the error "Component group not found in jdt..." appears. That's why I used the `remoteCommand` (so the javascript is defined there, and this does not check weather the component exists or not). But process was the right hint: adding `process="@this"` to the `remoteCommand` seems to solve the problem! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: or just find out what is the absolute id of your generated div in webtools and update it directly instead of using hacks like remotecommand.

Comment: I've tried this, but even if I got the exact id (its just `group` if I'm setting `prependId` in the form to false), it isn't finding the element. My explanation for this behaviour is, that one can't update a father-element in a child-element, because the father element isn't fully created at this time. So two solutions I could imagine was using `remoteCommand` or creating a second line out of the `h:panelGroup`, where I have to asure that the buttons are below the inputs, and so the `remoteCommand` solution seemed better to me.

Comment: you did put a colon in front of your updated id, right?   `<h:form id="form> <h:panelGroup id="group"> ...       <p:commandButton update=":form:group"/>
 `